# Where should I add GOOGLE_ANALYTICS_REGISTRATION_WITH_AD_NETWORK_ENABLED?

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-analytics

I'm reading *Firebase* [release notes](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/ios#analytics_3) and it seems that after version *6.29.0* they've adapted to the new iOS 14 tracking requirements and they offer a way to not automatically initialize `SKAdNetwork`:

> [SKAdNetwork registerAppForAdNetworkAttribution] is now automatically called on first open by default. To opt-out of this default behavior, add the key GOOGLE_ANALYTICS_REGISTRATION_WITH_AD_NETWORK_ENABLED with Boolean value NO to your app’s Info.plist file.

I want to trigger `SKAdNetwork` myself, but it's unclear to me if by app's `Info.plist` they mean:

- **Option 1:** The `Info.plist` created when you do Xcode, File, New, Project (the one that contains URLTypes, App Schemes, ...)
- **Option 2:** `GoogleService-Info.plist`

I think they mean option 1, but I'm not totally sure as everything in Firebase is usually configured by option 2.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's Option 1.

The `GoogleService-Info.plist` is supposed to be unused unmodified from the Firebase console download and is backend configuration information.

The app's `Info.plist` is for app specific configurations.